# Как бороться с нежелательным трафиком на сайт?

Tags: трафик, спам

Всех приветствую камрады. Есть сайт - [paku-paka.com.ua](https://paku-paka.com.ua/ru/) На него в последнее время замечаю переходы с китайских IP. Что посоветуете сделать, чтоб ограничить доступ таким посещениям?
Также, валится много спама через формы, гугл-капча стоит, но это не решаете проблем. Дайте совет, что делать пожалуйста.

Comment: Просто заблокировать все китайские IP?

Comment: Если трафик действительно большой, то нужно пользоваться моментом и монетизировать его за счёт рекламодателей. Но раз вы рекламируете свой сайт размещением ссылок где угодно, значит с трафиком на самом деле плохо...

Answer (score 0):

вообще исключи все переходы с китайских IP, тем более у тебя все равно траф украинский должен идти, судя по домену. Если не знаешь как это сделать, можешь попросить у своего хостера, они тебе сделают это. А со спамом хз как бороться, спамеры даже капчи научились обходить, поэтому ХЗ что делать.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить капчу на Google Invisible recaptcha. Много хороших отзывов и для посетителя сайта не нужно выискивать картинки.

Также можно защитить сайт от ботов и спама с помощью сторонних сервисов по типу Cloudflare. "Лишний" трафик будет отрезаться сразу при входе на сайт.